# How is the individual SAN elements controlled?

Tags: san

In a SAN environment, we would have multiple storage devices (say each of them with 1TB), so cumulatively the formed SAN network would give a 100's of GBs of storage capacity.

Which is the software that is responsible to splice this storage capacity to each VMs (say 500GB for each VMs)? Where does it reside?

I am finding it hard to picture this concept.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on various technologies there are multiple ways to do this. For example, in block-storage environments, LUNs from different storage systems can be concatenated/striped/mirrored/RAIDed by a volume manager software on the target server. The same effect can be achieved by hardware virtualisation on storage systems: for example, one of the storage device can work as "roof" for all the rest of devices (also, look at the thin-provisioning topic). In NAS world, it's possible to use build big trees of filesystems using different mount-points for different storage systems.